# Option selected in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the option item selected in a form select element using Codeigniter

model

```
function get_sections_provider($provider)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('providers');
    $this->db->where('providers.id', $provider);
    $this->db->join('sections', 'sections.id = providers.section_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function get_all_sections_element()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('sections');
    return $query->result();
}
```

controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $data['element'] = $this->admin_model_providers->get_element_provider($id);
    $data['element']->sections = $this->admin_model_providers->get_sections_provider($id);
    $data['element']->sections_all = $this->admin_model_providers->get_all_sections_element();
    $data['title'] = '';
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_provider_edit', $data);
}
```

view

```
<?
foreach($element->sections as $key => $row){
    $selected[$key] = $row->id;
}?>
<select name="sections" class="chosen-select" id="" data-placeholder="" multiple>                           
    <?
    foreach($element->sections_all as $key => $value){?>
        <option value="<?=$value->id?>" <?=(in_array($value->id, $selected) ) ? "selected = 'selected'" : "" ;?> ><?=$value->title;?></option>
    <?}
    ?>
</select>
```

The result is the last id
Sorry, I can not describe in detail the problem because my English is bad

Comment: Can you please show us the array structure you are getting within $element

Comment: Are you getting an array within `$data['element']->sections` or single value.

Comment: If I do so
foreach($element->sections as $key => $row){
    echo $row->id;
}
there are multiple

Comment: So are you using `$data['element']->sections` at multiple places within page or its been used just for `select` option if its been used for one select than please consider that you will receive only particular id from query

Comment: yes, i use this data for one select. So I can`t use this construction to select multiple options?

Comment: See if you are getting value of particular id from your query than it will be easy to select

Comment: You mean that I should initially to get the correct query?

Comment: Yep if you need only single value from `$data['element']->sections` than no need to get an entire array for respective

Comment: I'll try to explain the problem.
When editing items indicated 4 category of which are 3 active and 1 not

Comment: I made a screenshot..   http://prntscr.com/6kbfas

Comment: So you have multiple select values ok i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will may help you try this code if it works for you..

```
foreach($element->sections_all as $key => $value){
    <option value="<?php echo $value['id'];>" <?php echo (in_array($value['id']),$element['sections'][$key]['id']) ? "selected = 'selected'" : "" ;?>><?php echo $value['title'];?></option>
}
```

Comment: I change the query to the database, set result_array().. and corrected code.. 

<?foreach($sections_all as $key => $value){?>
        <option value="<?=$value['id']?>" <?=(in_array($value['id'], $sections[$key]['id'] )) ? "selected = 'selected'" : "" ;?> ><?=$value['title']?></option>
       <?}?>

Comment: Message:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Answer (score 2):

Try It:

```
<?php
  $array = null ; // $array[''] = 'Select'; // Use of need Default like Select 
  $select_value='';
   foreach ($element->sections as $value) {
     $array[$value->id] = $value->name;
   }
  echo form_dropdown('name', $array, $select_value, $style);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$selected` is an array. If you want to compare one of its elements in a foreach, try:

```
 foreach($element->sections as $key => $row){
    $selected[$key] = $row->id;
}
```

Foreach where comparison occurs:

```
foreach ($element->sections_all as $k => $section) {
    if ($section->id == $selected[$k]){
    //etc...
```